# Being fed a potion while having Spell resistance and while unconscious

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, spell-resistance

Normally with potions you are the caster and target, thus SR would not apply. But if you are force fed a potion is this still the case or would SR still deny the spell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Spell resistance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Spell-Resistance) doesn't interfere with a [potion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Spell-Resistance)'s effect

[Spell Resistance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Spell-Resistance) says that it "never interferes with [a creature's] own spells, items, or abilities."

"Potions are like spells cast upon the imbiber," says [Potions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/potions/) on Price of Potions, but "[t]he *drinker* is both the effective target and the *caster* of the effect" (emphasis mine). This should see a potion—barring specific exceptions—pretty much *always* ignore SR.

In other words, it's the *potion drinker* that matters. The creature feeding the potion to the potion drinker *doesn't* matter: the drinker's still doing the drinking.